# On average, how many times a user came before making first purchase?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id(pk)      user_id(int)    came_to_site(date_time)     purchases(int)
1           1               27-8-2016:10:12:23              0
2           2               27-8-2016:10:20:23              0
3           1               28-8-2016:10:12:23              1
4           3               29-8-2016:10:12:23              0
5           4               29-8-2016:11:40:23              0
6           4               30-8-2016:10:12:23              0
7           4               30-8-2016:12:12:23              1
8           1               30-8-2016:12:30:23              1
```

I have this table, I want to know, on average, how many times a user came before making first purchase.

- We can ignore user 2 and 3 because they never made a purchase.
- User 1 came 2 times before making a purchase.
- User 4 came 3 times before making a purchase.

So average would be (2 + 3)/2 = 2.5

Any idea how can I write such a query?

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data, and also specify the (new) expected result!

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY? And it might be clearer if you arranged by user and purchase date

Comment: Can purchases be more than 1? How is this determined?

Comment: @Jonny, yes there can be more than one. But it doesn't matter. See the last record, it doesn't affect the average.

Comment: It just seems a bit strange to design the database that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select avg(cnt)
from
(
    select user_id, 1 + count(*) as cnt
    from tablename t1
    where purchases = 0
      and exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                    and t2.purchases = 1)
      and not exists (select 1 from tablename t3
                      where t3.user_id = t1.user_id
                        and t3.purchases = 1
                        and t3.came_to_site < t1.came_to_site)
    group by user_id
)
```

The sub-query counts each user_id that has made a purchase (`EXISTS`), but not before current row (`NOT EXISTS`).

At main level, do `AVG()` to get average number.

Perhaps, depending on dbms, you need to do `avg(cnt * 1.0)` to avoid integer result.

Comment: it gives me 1.5, where I believe it should return 2.5 on given data.

Comment: User 1 was there 1 time before making first purchase, and user 2 times. Avg 1.5. Wait, you mean incl first purchase. Will edit! Done!

Answer (score 0):

Find the first purchase date of all users that made a purchase, then join to that:

```
select avg(visits)
from (select t.user_id, count(*) visits
      from (select user_id, min(came_to_site) first
            from mytable
            where purchases > 0
            group by user_id) fpd
      join mytable t on t.user_id = fpd.user_id and t.came_to_site < fpd.came_to_site) x
```

With an index on `user_id` this will perform pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
SELECT AVG(cpt) FROM (
    SELECT sales_user.user_id, COUNT(*) AS cpt
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE purchases=1) sales_user
    JOIN users ON sales_user.user_id=users.user_id
    WHERE users.came_to_site < sales_user.came_to_site
    GROUP BY sales_user.user_id);
```